# Make a select list of a custom post type in a meta box

Tags: custom-post-types

Simple you will say?

I have a first Custom post type called Country.
I have a second Custom post type called Travellers.
I need to make a drop down select list (multiple check) available when editing Countrywith content from Travellers.
This will allow me to select travellers for each country.

Help!

thx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display list of tags as drop down menu or radio buttons in a meta box?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7349/display-list-of-tags-as-drop-down-menu-or-radio-buttons-in-a-meta-box)

Answer (score 1):

very simeler to the question here [Display list of tags as drop down menu or radio buttons in a meta box?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7349/display-list-of-tags-as-drop-down-menu-or-radio-buttons-in-a-meta-box/7353#7353)

but instead of list of tags you need to query the post list of your travellers post type
something like this:

```
$travelers = new WP_Query();
$travelers ->query('post_type=travelers&postprepage=-1');
while ($travelers->have_posts()) : 
   $recentPosts->the_post();
   $travellersnames[] = $post->title;
endwhile
```

and show the $travellersnames as your option for a select filed or multi select filed in your meta box

Comment: glad i can help

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer I ended up with

```
$s_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'post_type' => 'slide'));
while($s_query->have_posts()):$s_query->the_post();

    $sname = $post->post_title;
    $s_output2 ='';
    $s_output2 .= '<option value="'.$post->ID.'" >';
    $s_output2 .= $post->post_title;
    $s_output2 .= '</option>';
    echo $s_output2;

endwhile ;
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to accomplish this same thing, but the code here is not working for me... is the syntax all correct? I have a basic working knowledge of PHP, but I can't tell what's going on here.

Perhaps some clarification?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My original question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/custom-post-types-titles-as-taxonomies

Comment: Hi ben, the code works by querying a custom taxonomy , in my example slide. May be paste your code and let see if we can help

Comment: Ben, please do not use an Answer to ask a question. Either start a new question, or post a comment (either to the OP here, or to one of the answers). Once you've done that please delete your answer here.

Comment: Sorry about that! I hesitated at first but this thread would not allow me to comment on previous answers for some reason. I see the last answer has been reformatted placing the code in the code box, so I'll mess with that and delete this answer...