# Include CPT values in another CPT?

Tags: custom-post-types, multi-taxonomy-query

I'm trying to add CPT values in a drop-down menu within another CPT, not sure if this is do-able.  Basically I have a Store CPT and a Manager CPT, in the manager cpt i have regular posts with the title, featured image, etc and what I would like to do is when I add a new store (on the Store CPT) i'd like to have a drop-down menu filled with the titles of Managers to be selected and associated, so that on the store page I can display the store manager as well.

A point in the right direction would be appriciated.

*CPT = Custom Post Type

Answer (score 1):

Three suggestions:

#### 1. Create Your Own Metabox

This is your original idea: when creating/editing the Store post type, the metabox will display a dropdown with all the available Managers of this post type.

For that, use Bainternet's answer to [this Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/7349/12615) as a starting point, and change the `get_categories` for a [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) of your CPT.
This will be stored as post meta and retrieved normally with a [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

---

#### 2. Use Post 2 Posts Plugin

<sup>[wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/)</sup>
I never really used this one, but I know it's done for this kind of scenario and its author is a WordPress heavy weight...

*In both plugin cases, read the documentation for the retrieval method.*

---

#### 3. Use Advanced Custom Fields Plugin

<sup>[wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)</sup>
Another actively maintained plugin with plenty of custom fields goodies.

The field types `Relationship` or `Post Object` can be used for this purpose.

Bellow the screenshots of a test configuration using the post types Movies and Actors with a Relationship field (more complex than Post Object, which would produce a simple dropdown).

**Field Configuration**
<sub>click to enlarge</sub>
[image: field configuration]

**Field Result**
<sub>click to enlarge</sub>
[image: field result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plug-in, or you can do it yourself with something like the following (untested):

```
<?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpa71126_add_meta_box' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp71126_save_post' );

function wpa71126_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'wpa71126_meta_box',
        __( 'Managers', 'textdomain' ),
        'wpa71126_meta_box',
        'manager' 
    );
}

function wpa71126_meta_box( $post ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'manager',
        'name'      => 'wpa71126_manager_dropdown'
    );

    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'wp71126_nonce' );

    echo '<label>';
    _e('Select a manager', 'textdomain' );
    wp_dropdown_pages( $args );
    echo '</label> ';
}

function wp71126_save_post( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'wp71126_nonce' ], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
      return;

    // Check permissions
    if ( 'manger' == $_POST[ 'post_type' ] )  {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
          return;
    }

    $manager = $_POST[ 'wpa71126_manager_dropdown' ];

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manager', $manager );
}
```

Comment: How would I show that in the front end though?

Comment: You can still use `wp_dropdown_pages()` on the front end, but I am not sure how because I do not have your code in front of me. Please update your question with the code that you are using to do the front end editing.